# /media folder nearly full - /media/vids folder has 500gb free

Tags: hard-drive, directory, mountpoint

Weird error.
I have a 1Tb HDDmounted as my main file repository. It is mounted as /media/Vids.
When I check properties of /media it says 2Gb free.

When I check properties of /media/Vids it says 586Gb free.  Torrent down loader says not enough space to continue downloads to /media/Vids.

Can anyone explain

Comment: can you post the output of `df -h`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing weird about that. As you stated, you mounted your 1TB disk on `/media/Vids`, and that's where the full space went to. However, `/media` is **not** on that 1TB disk, but just the *logical* place your disk got "organized under". Most likely, media is just part of your root file system (mounted at `/`). And that's on a different disk, as you could evaluate using one of the following commands:

- `mount`
- `df -h`

Both will list the devices along -- and you will see different devices reported for the mentioned directories.

Comment: PS: "Nothing weird" referred to the reporting of free space by your "check". Please check what you configured as download folder in Torrent Downloader, and make sure that starts at least with `/media/Vids` (and does not simply point to `/media` or even starts completely different).